# Supplied String module notation 'libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar' is invalid

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to get Mobile GTS' prebuilt Candy Jump app to run and build an APK in Android Studio. I've followed this video precisely: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YpYVdJVYWg0.

However, I am using Gradle 4.7, JDK 1.8.0, Android Plugin Version 3.1.2 and Build Tools Version 27.0.3. I'm not sure if that would have anything to do with why I can't get it to build, but I've had error after error and I've kind of boiled it down to what I hope is the last error.

> Supplied String module notation 'libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar' is invalid. Example notations: 'org.gradle:gradle-core:2.2', 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5:javadoc'.

How can I fix this error?

Here's my build.gradle (module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "net.mobilegts.candyjump"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 27
            multiDexEnabled true

            ndk {
                moduleName "player_shared"
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                shrinkResources false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }


        }
        sourceSets.main {
            jni.srcDirs = []// <-- disable automatic ndk-build call
        }
        productFlavors {
        }
    }

dependencies {
    implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services:+') { exclude module: 'support-v4' }
    implementation 'libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar'
    implementation 'libs/javax.inject-1.jar'
    implementation 'libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar'
    implementation 'libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use "implementation files" for jar files. Try the following code:

```
implementation files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
implementation files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
implementation files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
```